# Return of a string function

Tags: c++, string, vector, return

i cannot `return` if some of the `strings` appear more than once.

i.e i have two `vectors` and i search the `1st` `vector` with the `2nd` `vector` and if some of the `elements` from the `2nd vector` appear more than once in the `1st vector` i want to `return` an error but for some reason i only can `return` if the elements in the `1st vector` do not appear more than once

my code is below

I want to `return s1` when elements have appeared more than once how can i do that i tried having it infront of the `break` but that did not work

```
std::vector<std::string> test; //vector that comes in
test.push_back("YES");
test.push_back("YES");
//test.push_back("NO");
test.push_back("NO");

std::vector<std::string> test1; // vector from DB..
test1.push_back("YES");
test1.push_back("NO");

std::string s ("Element count is fine");
std::string s1 ("Element count is incorrect");
for(int i = 0; i < test1.size(); i++)
{
    if(count(test.begin(), test.end(),test1[i]) > 1)
    {
        return s1;
    }
}

return s;
```

Comment: please add some fullstops somewhere.

Comment: Look at your break. It exists the forloop, not the if statement.

Comment: "i tried having it infront of the break but that did not work" => What happened exactly?

Comment: It did not output the text for s1 @Unni

Comment: Is this the actual code you are running? It should work now with your modification.

Comment: Yes this is the exact code i am running and `s1` is still not outputting @PeterWood

Comment: @ShamariCampbell What's the output code like? Modify the example to make a running example, that we can also run, and tell us the expected output and actual output.

Answer (score 2):

Change the loop to:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < test1.size(); i++)
    {
        if(count(test.begin(), test.end(),test1[i]) > 1)
        {
        //  DCS_LOG_DEBUG("Some elements have appeared more than once...");
            return s1;
        }
    }
```

`return` breaks out of all control structures and leaves the current function. You old code was returning `s1` almost every time, because the `return s1` was not guarded by the `if`.

Comment: oh ok so now if i change that it will `return s1` when it enters the if block hmm yeah i think it will work as it was not `returning` the text for `s1` before

Comment: Hm it still doees not return s1 when i have my code like that either @Mankarse

Comment: Hi @Mankarse this still not working it returns s1 all the time :/

Answer (score 0):

I think the code is right. It works fine on my computer. Maybe you can output something inside the if to see what really going on.

```
    if(count(test.begin(), test.end(),test1[i]) > 1)
    {
        cout<<"The count is "<<count(test.begin(), test.end(),test1[i])<<endl;
        return s1;
    }
```